# which is better way to load page content in jQuery mobile and Phonegap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile-safari

I am building the iOS app use jQuery mobile and Phonegap.
I build the website and test in PC browser,so I put the backend code(use Ruby) in the html file , so when jQuery load the page (use $.mobile.changePage()) the data will fetch from server and render the template file.(all file on the server).

But when I put codes in Phonegap, **the index.html file will now on the local,is that my only way to fetch the server side data is to make a AJAX request to fetch the json and insert to the page**?or any other way perform better?

And the jquery mobile use $.mobile.changePage() to change page using a AJAX request , so if I do make the request to fetch data , the $.mobile.changePage() function here only do the transition  , because of it did not load any data for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax requests are a good way to go for loading remote content. If you want to load content when a page is shown do something like this:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {
    $.get('http://domain.com/path_to_script.php?id=blah', function (data) {
        $(this).children('[data-role="content"]').html(data);
    });
});
```

NOTE: this example expects that the non-local script will output html ready to insert into the dom. You can receive any type of data you would like and parse it however you would like; the data variable returns the response from the ajax request.

Comment: "this" is what jquery mobile **is all about.** but [it's hilarious to see them trying to use big, bold letters in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html) to hammer these ideas ion the bewildered masses... when it's like THEY don't even get it! HA! No, but for real, this is important, and confusing..  Your answer says to me.. "you get it".  is there any more you can add, though?  i am still confused as to how i can load a complete `<div id="blah2" data-role="page"...</div>` fragment from the server like it does from another `div` on "the page".

Comment: @alexgray You can `.append()` the `data-role="page"` element and its contents to the `body` element. Then if you use a 'click` event handler to direct the user to the new page using the `$.mobile.changePage()` function the jQuery Mobile framework will initialize and transition to the new `data-role="page"` element. Here is a jsfiddle demnstration: http://jsfiddle.net/nbpdy/1/